# Tracking Not Installed on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed following google analytics code on my website.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'findlight.net');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I can see the code in page source. But on the Admin page, it shows "Status: Tracking Not Installed"

I tried looking at Real Time dashboard. It's not working there as well. Help!!

Comment: Check the js console for any errors and install the [GA debugger for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en). Hopefully between the two you can figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your admin template the same as the rest of the site? If the code works on the rest of the site there is probably something different about your admin template. Also, when pasting code, I would not include account information like your analytics id (UA-XXXXXX-X).

Several tools that can help you when debugging GA:

- [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) - I have found this incredibly helpful
- [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en), as jk mentioned